# Why do I keep randomly losing health and dying?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I keep losing health and I thought it was a bugged mission, so I went back to a previous save. However, it happens in every save, I tried asking the Discussion on Steam, and someone told me to type <kbd>~</kbd> and type `disable` then `enable`.

It keeps happening, I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: What mods do you have installed, if any?

Comment: Kinda vague. Please add more details. How fast are you losing the health? Is there any animation or visual indicator? Is there anything listed on your Active Effects page? Are you wearing any magical equipment?

Comment: No Indicators, No active effects, no animation, and losing health varies on how much health I have. Full health maybe 5 seconds, 1/8th of health bar, no time at all.

Comment: and Frank, I have unofficial skyrim patch, 100x Carry Weight, Locational Damage, Path of Shadows, Dance of Death, and Sneak Tools.

Comment: Just confirming, are you a Werewolf/Vampire? Did you contract any diseases?

Comment: I am a Vampire, and no contracted no disease. Also, the sun thing, I keep losing health indoors.

Comment: Are you drowning? It sounds like you are drowning somehow.

Comment: Or, have you used a black book recently?

Comment: No I haven't and no I'm not in water, however, I tried setting my health to a crazy high amount and going back to a previous save, it seems to be working for now.

Comment: You might also want to try to validate your files.

Comment: Have you gone to the Soul Cairn recently?

Comment: _Locational Damage_ can cause bleeding, but I'm sure you checked for that. Try disabling the mods one by one and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Pro tip: You have some close votes for your question being unclear. You have given us enough additional information in comments that those votes would probably not be valid if you edited the information into the question. You generally don't get credit for stuff in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I did, I deleted a mod called "Infinite Money Merchants" and then went back to a previous save before I had gotten the Nightweavers band. That's how I got it to work. So far, have killed the emperor and no problems. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Have you since re-enabled the mod? Also, that mod wasn't in the list you gave us.